# No puedo condicionar la entrada de usuarios dependiendo de un atributo

Tags: php, mysql

He intentado condicionar la entrada de alumnos dependiendo el tipo de alumno que es "RG","RP","RI" o "NV". 
Necesito saber en qué cosa he fallado o qué me falta para tener una validación exitosa.
Tenía entendido que se podría hacer con sesiones, pero no sabría como implemetarlo.

Conexión a base datos:

```
<?php
        $servidor="localhost";
        $usuario="root";
        $clave="";
        $baseDeDatos="inscripcion";
        try{
            $db=new PDO("mysql:host={$servidor};dbname={$baseDeDatos}",$usuario,$clave);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
            $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

La validación

```
        $consultaRI = "SELECT dni_alumno FROM alumno WHERE tipo_alumno='RI'";
        $consultaRP = "SELECT dni_alumno FROM alumno WHERE tipo_alumno='RP'";
        $consultaRG = "SELECT dni_alumno FROM alumno WHERE tipo_alumno='RG'";
        $consultaNV = "SELECT dni_alumno FROM alumno WHERE tipo_alumno='NV'";

        if(isset($_POST['btnIngresar'])){
            $usuario = $_POST['txtUsuario'];
            if($usuario = $consultaRI){
                mysqli_query($enlace,$consultaRI);
                header ("Location: Acceso_Matricula_Reingresante.php");
            }
            elseif($usuario = $consultaRP){
                mysqli_query($enlace,$consultaRP);
                header ("Location: Acceso_Matricula_Repitencia.php");
            }
            elseif($usuario = $consultaRG){
                mysqli_query($enlace,$consultaRG);
                header ("Location: Acceso_Matricula_Regular.php");
            }
            elseif($usuario = $consultaNV){
                mysqli_query($enlace,$consultaNV);
                header ("Location: Acceso_Matricula_Nuevo.php");
            }else{
                echo "F";
            }
        }   
?>
```

Contestando a los comentarios; dejando de lado el PDO, una manito con la validación apropiada por favor.

```
$servidor="localhost";
        $usuario="root";
        $clave="";
        $baseDeDatos="inscripcion";
        $enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);
        
        if(!$enlace){
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: Hola. La sintaxis que usas para crear la conexión PDO me toma por sorpresa. Siempre he usado algo tan simple como `$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);` sin esas llaves dentro de la cadena que muestras. Por favor revisa [La clase PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo)

Comment: **Nota importante:** es posible que necesites la sentencia `use PDO;` al principio de tu archivo de script php en el que creas la conexión, pues PDO no está activo por defecto. Está disponible pero no necesariamente activo.

Comment: @quevedo esa forma también es correcta ([ver la doc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php)), simplemente está pasando el DSN y demás cosas hardcoded. Y, realmente no tiene que poner `use PDO` sino asegurarse que el mismo está instalado y/o activado en `php.ini` , generalmente no hay problemas con eso, a no ser que se haya desactivado a propósito. Álvaro, una de las cosas graves que veo en tu código es **una mezcla de APIs**, por un lado intentas conectar con PDO pero por otro usas `mysqli` para las consultas. `PDO` y `mysqli`  son dos APIs totalmente distintas.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo he tenido casos en que PDO, no está activo a pesar de haber referencia en .ini (si no tengo un autoloader) por eso la nota. **Gracias por la anotación acerca de la cadena de conexión.**

Comment: @quevedo me suena raro eso, ¿quizá te refieres a una clase envoltorio que gestiona la conexión a PDO? Si PDO está debidamente instalado en PHP (se podría verificar mediante `phpinfo()` por ejemplo)  no debería haber problema ninguno en usar `new PDO(...)`  desde cualquier parte sin necesidad de autoloader ni nada por el estilo. En cambio, si es una clase envoltorio es claro que debes ponerla en contexto con autoloader, include u otro.

Comment: @A.Cedano **No sólo a ti te suena raro** yo creía poder usarlo directo cuando me pasó; estaba en una instalación limpia de zendframework 3.x, estaba probando a usar PDO directamente, y las sentencias de tipo `new PDO(...)` generaban error fatal; que se resolvió con el uso del llamado explícito `use PDO;`

Comment: Ya, realmente no uso frameworks, he usado PDO siempre en programas que residen en un hosting remoto, nunca en local ni con frameworks. Allí PDO está instalado en el módulo de PHP y puedo usarlo en cualquiera de mis archivos con `new PDO`  sin más, @quevedo.